# Find whether function is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, continuity

The whole exercise has a number of different functions and they're asking us to decide whether the function is or isn't continuous.

This is the first case:

$$g(x) = \frac{-(x-2)^{2}}{\left | x-2 \right |+2-x}$$

And this is the second case:

$$h(x) = \frac{\left | x-1 \right |}{x-1}$$

My work so far:
For function $g $  I've determined that the function is continuous because there are no gaps in its domain (which is $ \left ( -\propto, 2  \right )$, considering that we have to exclude all numbers $>2$.

And I think that the second function ($f$) is continuous as well.

But I'm not really sure.

We haven't covered $limits$ at school yet, only the delta-epsilon definition of continuity.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, both are continuous on their domains. Domain of the second function is $\{x: x \neq 1\}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm But if there are exceptions (gaps) in the domain of the second function, is it still continuous?

Comment: The domain is $(-\infty,1)\cup (1,\infty)$ and the function is continuous there.